# What advantages does Notification class give over simply sending email with Laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel

There was introduced a new notification class in Laravel 5.3 which allows pushing notifications to different channels. It does allow to quickly throw multiple lines and give a call to action and also allows sending notifications to multiple users with a single method call.

Are there any other advantages that I might have missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notfications allow for emails, slack, sms, etc to be all applied in one place under a single notification, where Mailables are just mail.

Notification email does provide a dynamic template for composing an email using the MailMessage API, but it also allows you to just use a view of your choosing instead using `(new MailMessage)->view('location.name')->...`.

As of v5.3.15 you can also now return Mailables instead of MailMessage from Notifications allowing for the use of a much more robust mail API that includes Cc, Bcc, etc.

So basically now you can get the best of both worlds when using Notifications now that you can implement Mailables within them instead of using MailMessage.